# How do you plot vertical bar?

Tags: c++, math

My professor has given us Lothar Collatz's mathematical observation, which is:

- If the integer is even, divide it by two.
- If the integer is odd, triple it and add one.

Do this repeatedly and the number will eventually become 1.

```
Ex: input: 8 has 3 steps

8/2 = 4 
4/2 = 2 
2/2 = 1

Ex 2: input: 12 has 9 steps

12 / 2     =  6
 6 / 2     =  3
 3 * 3 + 1 = 10
10 / 2     =  5
 5 * 3 + 1 = 16
16 / 2     =  8
 8 / 2     =  4
 4 / 2     =  2
 2 / 2     =  1
```

My instructions are to take however many steps a number may have and plot them in a vertical bar. However, I am also supposed to plot vertical bars for the next 19 numbers after the initial input. (Total of 20)

```
Ex:
input: 7 has 16 steps
                                                      ##
                                                      ##
                                                      ##
                                 ## ##                ##
      ##                         ## ##                ##
      ##                         ## ##                ##
      ##             ## ##       ## ##                ##
##    ##             ## ##       ## ##                ##
##    ##             ## ##       ## ##       ## ##    ##
##    ##    ##       ## ##       ## ##       ## ##    ##
##    ##    ##       ## ##       ## ##       ## ##    ##
##    ##    ##       ## ##    ## ## ##       ## ##    ##
##    ##    ##       ## ##    ## ## ##       ## ##    ##
##    ##    ##       ## ##    ## ## ##       ## ## ## ## ##
##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##       ## ## ## ## ##
##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##       ## ## ## ## ##
##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
##    ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
##    ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
##    ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
```

My problem is I can't seem to get my code to work. 
Here is what I have:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
void plot_range(int starting_number);
int count_steps(int starting_number);

int main()
{
  int starting_number;
  cout << "Enter a starting number to plot." << endl;
  cin >> starting_number;
  plot_range(starting_number);
  return 0;
}


void plot_range(int starting_number)
{
   int tallest_bar = 0;
   count_steps(starting_number);

  for (int i = count_steps(starting_number); i < count_steps(starting_number) + 20; i++){

    if (count_steps(i) > tallest_bar){

        tallest_bar = count_steps(i);
    }
}
for (tallest_bar; tallest_bar > 0 ; tallest_bar--){
    for (int i = count_steps(starting_number); i < count_steps(starting_number) + 20; i++) {

          if(count_steps(i) >= tallest_bar ){

            cout << "## ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "   ";
        }
    }
 cout << endl;
}

}


int count_steps(int starting_number)
{
  int steps=0;
   while (starting_number != 1) {

    if (starting_number % 2 == 0) {
        starting_number = starting_number / 2;
        steps++;
    }

    else {
        starting_number = (starting_number * 3) + 1;
        steps++;
    }

  }

  return steps;
}
```

This is my output when I input 7:

```
                                 ##
                                 ##
                                 ##
                                 ##
                                 ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##
                                 ##          ##    ##
                                 ##          ##    ##
                                 ##          ##    ##
                           ##    ##          ##    ##
                           ##    ##          ##    ##
                           ##    ##          ##    ##
      ## ##                ##    ##          ##    ##
      ## ##                ##    ##          ##    ##
      ## ##                ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ##
      ## ##                ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ##
      ## ##                ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ##
      ## ##       ## ##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ##
      ## ##       ## ##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ##
      ## ##       ## ##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ##       ## ##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ##       ## ##    ##    ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ##       ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ##       ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ##       ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##    ## ## ##
   ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
```

Note: The output should be identical to example bars I have shown above. I am using the same input.
`main` and `count_steps(starting_number)` are given.

Comment: What output does your code give? Add that to the question as well.

Comment: I would have, but I don't get any output back. The program compiles, but when I enter a number, the program stalls and does nothing.

Comment: Then add that information to the question. You need to say what your program does.

Comment: Done. Also added my professor's instructions

Comment: You might want to step through the code with a debugger to see where it is getting stuck. Take a look at the values of variables and make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: I actually fixed part of my code (Updated it here). I am now receiving an output with 20 bars, however the amount of bars I am outputting is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

figured out the issue. I was receiving the correct output, however the program wasn't displaying bars 7 to 15, it was displaying 16 to 35 (19 bars after 16).
Therefore I changed my two for loops from

```
for (int i = count_steps(starting_number); i < count_steps(starting_number) + 20; i++)
{...}
```

to

```
for (int i = starting_number; i < starting_number + 20; i++)
{...}
```

Now it works correctly.